Proper definition of interval columns in a table
I want to build a table that defines a "classification" for a value in an interval, I can't have conflicts in the intervals.
The data will look like this:



Country
StartAge
StopAge
Classification




US
0
3
baby


US
4
12
child


US
13
20
teenage


...
...
...
...


BR
0
3
baby


BR
4
10
child


BR
11
18
teenage


...
...
...
...



Note: there cannot be any range conflicts for the same combination of Country, StartAge, and StopAge. For example, inserting a row like ("US", 18, 28, "young adult") must be blocked by conflict with ("US", 13, 20, "teenage").
Is there any way to create a table with these properties?

You probably need a trigger verifying this or a view with a unique constraint which makes sure there aren't any overlaps

Is it possible to have gaps in the ranges, ie (US, child) stops 11 but (US, teenage) still starts at 13, with nothing remaining to pick up year 12?

There's a couple of ways of doing this. You can't do this explicitly within the table's properties, such as using an INDEX or CONSTRAINT, but you could use a VIEW or a TRIGGER.
First, some sample data:
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY, --We need this for the trigger
                            Country char(2) NOT NULL,
                            StartAge tinyint NOT NULL,
                            StopAge tinyint NOT NULL,
                            Classification varchar(20) NOT NULL,
                            CONSTRAINT Chk_YourTable_StartStopAge CHECK (StopAge >= StartAge)); 
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES('US',0,3,'baby'),
      ('US',4,13,'child'),
      ('US',14,20,'teenage'); --Changed 13 to 14 to make valid

A VIEW might also offer additional functionality, as we're going to generate a row for every age for your data, so it seems the better™ solution. To solve the problem we're going to put a UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX on the VIEW instead. So we can use GENERATE_SERIES for that and then JOIN (we can't APPLY due to constraints on indexed views) and then we can create a UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX on the Country and Age:
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourView
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
    SELECT YT.Country,
           GS.value AS Age,
           YT.Classification
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         JOIN GENERATE_SERIES(0,200,1) GS ON GS.[value] BETWEEN YT.StartAge AND YT.StopAge; --Can't use APPLY with an indexed VIEW. 200 as should be high enough
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UI_YourView ON dbo.YourView (Country,Age)

Now if we try to INSERT the row you define it fails:
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable 
VALUES('US', 18, 28, 'young adult');


Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 28
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.YourView' with unique index 'UI_YourView'. The duplicate key value is (US, 18).

Attempting a valid row works fine:
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable 
VALUES('US', 21, 29, 'young adult');

The alternative would be to use a TRIGGER instead. You (might have) noticed I added a primary key to the table earlier; this is important so that in the TRIGGER we don't detect the row we just inserted. As long as you have a Primary key of some kind, and check that the values don't match this will be fine.
--If you are testing this, DROP the VIEW first; it's a one or the other solution, not both.
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.YourTrigger ON dbo.YourTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM dbo.YourTable YT
                    JOIN inserted i ON YT.Country = i.Country
                                   AND (YT.StartAge BETWEEN i.StartAge AND i.StopAge
                                    OR  YT.StopAge BETWEEN i.StartAge AND i.StopAge)
                                   AND YT.ID != i.ID) BEGIN
        --I like my error messages frpm triggers to be descriptive, and I can easily deploy this script to any trigger
        DECLARE @TriggerName sysname,
                @TableName sysname;
        SELECT @TriggerName = tr.name,
               @TableName = t.name
        FROM sys.tables t
             JOIN sys.triggers tr ON t.object_id = tr.parent_id
        WHERE tr.object_id = @@PROCID;
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage nvarchar(2000) = FORMATMESSAGE(N'An error occurred in the trigger ''%s'' on the object ''%s''. The values in the columns ''StartAge'' and ''StopAge'' overlapped with another row.', @TriggerName, @TableName);

        THROW 78625, @ErrorMessage, 16;
    END;
END;
GO

Again, an invalid row:
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable 
VALUES('US', 18, 28, 'young adult');


Msg 78625, Level 16, State 16, Procedure YourTrigger, Line 21
An error occurred in the trigger 'YourTrigger' on the object 'YourTable'. The values in the columns 'StartAge' and 'StopAge' overlapped with another row.
And a valid row:

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable 
VALUES('US', 30, 39, 'middle-age adult');


Note that you need an update trigger as well, or just add after update

Updated to include UPDATE, @siggemannen . I was testing against INSERTs and forgot to "unmuddy" the water. I admit, I prefer the VIEW.

One way to do this is to understand the StartAge value for any row can be inferred from the StopAge of the row prior, ie:
COALESCE(LAG(StopAge) OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY StopAge)+1,0) As StartAge

And therefore we only need to record the StopAge, and can omit StartAge from the table completely.

This holds true as long as there are no gaps in the ranges. Don't do this if, say, the US child range could stop at 11, but teenage still doesn't start until 13, with nothing else to cover year 12.
My intuition is there should not be gaps for this data, but the real world sometimes leaves us with an incomplete picture of what we hope to record.
It may also be you hoped to have a fallback / default value when there is no matching record (ie: coalesce([table].classification, 'person')), whereas this option requires you to generate rows for these situations, ie add a new (US, 12, person) row to cover the scenario mentioned previously.

If we can trust the "no gaps" rule, we can remove the StartAge column and have a simple UNIQUE constraint on (Country,StopAge). This makes it impossible to record a duplicate or overlapping range.
Finding the correct classification for a given country and age can also be done in a simple query with TOP:
SELECT TOP 1 classification 
FROM [table]
WHERE Country = @Country AND StopAge >= @Age
ORDER BY StopAge DESC

which can in turn be used as part of more-complex lookups via APPLY lateral join:
SELECT p.*, c.classification
FROM Person p
CROSS APPLY ( 
    -- used CROSS rather then OUTER to emphasize the need for a complete set
    SELECT TOP 1 classification
    FROM [table] t
    WHERE t.Country = p.Country AND t.StopAge >= p.Age 
    ORDER BY t.StopAge DESC
) c

or we can continue to use windowing:
WITH ClassificationRanges AS (
    SELECT Country, Classification, StopAge,
        COALESCE(LAG(StopAge) OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY StopAge)+1,0) As StartAge
    FROM [table]
)
SELECT *
FROM ClassificationRanges
WHERE Country = @Country AND @Age BETWEEN StartAge AND StopAge

If you really want to, you can also convert the window function query into to a View, such that changes (INSERT/UPDATE) are done via the base table (including the UNIQUE constraint), but retrieval (SELECT) can use the view which includes the StartAge column.

Finally, it is, of course, possible to invert this whole thing, recording only the StartAge and omitting the StopAge from the table. But I found StopAge easier to work with for this particular set.

Nice! I was forgetting to treat the gaps
